# Why does node.js works so strange with double question mark expression?

Tags: node.js

```
const a: string = 'asd'
const b: string = 'ddd'
const test = a ?? b === 'daa' ? 'ccc' : null
```

I have the following js code. For some reason test equals 'ccc' in this expression, but how? How is it possible. According to logic, test should equal 'asd', as we are using double question mark to check if a equals undefined or null, but it's not, so we should take the value from a.

We have this code in my work, and i was assigned a task to fix the bug. But i don't understand how this bug happened in the first place. Env: typescript, ts-node, node 18.12.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an operator precedence problem.  The ternary operator has very low precedence, so your expression is parsed as:

```
const test = (a ?? (b === 'daa')) ? 'ccc' : null
```

Since the result in parens is a true value, the result will be 'ccc'.  It is always a good idea to use extra parentheses to clarify ternary expressions.

```
const test = a ?? (b === 'daa' ? 'ccc' : null)
```